# How to extract a row with the maximal value?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, maximize

I have two tables and want to do the following. From the first table I extract all rows that fulfill a given condition. For all extracted rows I take a value from the first column. For every value I extract all raws from the second table that contain the given value in the first column. All raws extracted from the second table have to be ordered in a specific way and I want to take only one row that is the first (according to the ordering criteria). This is my problem, I do not know how to take one row with the highest value of the ordering criteria.

**ADDED**

The first table:

```
| aaa | Bob |
| bbb | Eva |
| ccc | Bob |
```

The second table:

```
| aaa | 111 | 1 |
| aaa | 342 | 2 |
| ccc | 576 | 1 |
| ccc | 749 | 3 |
```

From the first table I take all rows containing Bob. The first column in these rows contain the following values: "aaa" and "ccc". For "aaa" in the second table I have two rows and I want to take those that has the maximal value in the last column. So, I have `|aaa|342|2|`. The same I do with the "ccc". I take this row |ccc|749|3|. And finally I want to have the two rows ordered according to the value of the last column.

**ADDED 2**

I have just realized that the essence of the problem is as following. In a given table I want to **replace all rows containing the same value in the first columns by one "representative" row (that has the maximal value in the third column)**. In more details, I want to replace this table:

```
| aaa | 111 | 1 |
| aaa | 342 | 2 |
| ccc | 576 | 1 |
| ccc | 749 | 3 |
```

By this one:

```
| aaa | 342 | 2 |
| ccc | 749 | 3 |
```

Comment: mind to show us your mystery table schema? (and fix some typo)...

Comment: So you want to do all this in a single query and ultimately return a single row from the second table with the highest value of the ordering criteria?

Comment: @ajreal, it seems that we edited the post parsimoniously. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
select t2.* 
  from t1
  join t2 on t2.id = (select t2c.id 
                        from t2 as t2c 
                       where t2c.t1_id = t1.id 
                       order by t2c.val desc
                       limit 1)
 where t1.name = 'Bob'
 order by t2.val
```

You did not specify column names, so i made them up.

`t2.id` has to be unique.

Comment: your query looks correct. I am going to delete my answer. Just putting my comments again. I asked - can anybody tell me any free online database server where we can do all the things we can do on tools like PhpMyAdmin? does something like that exist? Like we have jsfiddle for testing js codes. I checked the sqlzoo.net suggested by you, but this does not allow me to do all things, there are some predefined tables etc. on that site on which I can test but cannot create my own.

Comment: asked a question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526445/free-online-tools-for-testing-mysql-queries-having-features-like-phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using correlated subqueries but the performance will be abysmal.

```
mysql> select * from user;
+--------+-----------+
| userid | user_name |
+--------+-----------+
| aaa    | Bob       |
| bbb    | Eva       |
| ccc    | Bob       |
+--------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user_data;
+--------+-------+------+
| userid | value | num  |
+--------+-------+------+
| aaa    |   111 |    1 |
| aaa    |   342 |    2 |
| ccc    |   576 |    1 |
| ccc    |   749 |    3 |
| bbb    |  1000 |    1 |
| bbb    |   800 |    2 |
+--------+-------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT u1.userid,u1.user_name,ud1.value from user_data ud1 join user u1 ON ud1.userid=u1.userid where ud1.value=(SELECT value FROM user_data ud2 WHERE ud2.userid=ud1.userid ORDER BY value desc LIMIT 1) AND u1.user_name='Bob';
+--------+-----------+-------+
| userid | user_name | value |
+--------+-----------+-------+
| aaa    | Bob       |   342 |
| ccc    | Bob       |   749 |
+--------+-----------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```